# Use Google OAuth2 token from different platforms

Tags: android, google-api, accountmanager

I use AccountManager to retrieve google accounts on the Android device. After it I asked user for token with some scope and after I get it, I want to send it to the server and use token for API calls from backend side.

So, my question is can I use AccountManager for this? Or only GoogleAuthUtil?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds very much like a use case for [Cross-client identity](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/CrossClientAuth).